# Printing a multidimensional array in php into an html table

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have been having some trouble printing my multi dimensional array into a table.  Right now I

```
    Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 00fa4033-421f-48d9-bc69-a0d9c9c4973e
            [name] => Chaka
        )

)
```

How can I output this data to an array.  The code I am using to print the array is the following

```
$response = $status->getStatus('104.243.39.107');

if (!$response) {
    echo '<h2>STATUS: <span class="label label-danger">Offline</span></h2>';
} else {
    echo '<h2>STATUS: <span class="label label-success">Online</span></h2>';
    echo "Online Players " .$response['players']."/".$response['maxplayers'];
    echo '<br /><pre>';
    print_r($response['sample']); //THIS LINE
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

I have tried many methods to fix this but I am new to php.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
echo '<table><tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th></tr>';
foreach ($response['sample'] as $player) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$player->id.'</td><td>'.$player->name.'</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```